# Order array by how much the key is like a specific string. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, levenshtein-distance

How can I order an array of results by how much the array's keys is like a specific string. If I have a string like this:

> Hello World

And an array:

```
array(
    [0] => "hello word"
    [1] => "herro world"
    [2] => "beho wors"
```

I tried using it with the Levenshtein function, but I couldn't get to understand how I could do it. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: please provide more information .. perhaps a glimpse at your failing code

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I really do not know how to??!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `usort()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), and have your compare function use the Levenshtein distance.

If that value is expensive to compute, then pre-compute it and store it in a separate array so that your compare function doesn't have to recompute it frequently during the sort.